# Align popup in middle along with navigation button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I want a image gallery similar to the design as show in fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fp4uq2w1/6/). It has been customized to look more what we are looking for but i have two issue with this right now

1. Popup is not aligned in the middle of the page. i tried changing few properties but that didnt work
2. How can i add working `Next` `Prev` button functionality to this gallery so that users dont have to click each time to view the next phone. I had looked at other galleries but each had one of the other problem when i tried to customize them.

I had tried to customize this gallery but i had same it i need to show image in a fixed box 600x300 pixel with image on left & text on right of the image.[image]

I also tried to modify `Magnific` popup almost change the script to work but this also  had an issue as it always start the galley from first image itself irrespective of which image users click on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvFxH

Comment: I'm not going to post an asnwer but vertical/horizontal alignment could be achieved like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fp4uq2w1/13/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fp4uq2w1/14/).

Comment: @HashemQolami, Thank you at-least one issue is solve. I will study your code to see what i missed.